# Text file not writing and storing data properly

Tags: android, file, read-write

I am having some problems with creating and editing text files. The file never seems to store the data.

- I need to create a text file, if one
  is not available.
- If there is data in the file, read that data and make it available.
- The data stored is a `String` comprising of three integer values, separated by a `,` Eg: `String finalWrite = "3,5,1"`
- So this string needs to be split up, and converted into integers to allow for addition of new counters.
- Those new counters need to be written into the text file stored on the device

There are no errors occurring, and no force closures.

I was only able to figure out that the values are not being stored properly, using Logcat.

I have reviewed documentation on the [Android](http://developer.android.com) development site. If anyone can help or point me in the right direction, it would be much appreciated!

The write method that I am using:

```
public void WriteItIn() throws IOException
{
    FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput("stats.txt", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
    OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
    ReadItIn(); //calls the read method, to get the values from the file
    int tmp1 = 0 + countertmp + counter;
    int tmp2 = 0 + counterpostmp + counterpos;
    int tmp3 = 0 + counternegtmp + counterneg;
    finalwrite = "" + tmp1 + "," + tmp2 + "," + tmp3;
    osw.write(finalwrite);
    osw.flush();
    osw.close();
}
```

The Read method:

```
public void ReadItIn() throws IOException
            {
                FileInputStream fIn = openFileInput("stats.txt");
                InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fIn);
                char[] inputBuffer = new char[fIn.available()];
                isr.read(inputBuffer);
                stringFromFile = new String(inputBuffer);
                String [] tmp = stringFromFile.split("\\,");
                if(tmp.length > 0)
                {
                    Log.d("READ", " NOT NULL");
                    for(int i = 0;i<tmp.length ; i++)
                    {
                        String temper = tmp[i];
                        if(temper == null || temper == "")
                        {
                                Log.d("NULL", "NULLIFIED");
                        }
                        else
                            try
                        {
                            int x = Integer.parseInt(temper, 10);
                            if(i == 0){counter = x;}
                            else if(i == 1){counterpos = x;}
                            else if(i == 2){counterneg = x;}
                        }
                        catch(NumberFormatException e)
                        {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }   
                }
                else
                    Log.d("READ", "NULL");
            }
```

Comment: so, the problem is that `tmp.lenght <= 0`? my regexp experience is a bit rusty but have you tried splitting by `","` instead of `"\\,"`?

Comment: Yes I have tried splitting both ways. I think that the splitting isnt the problem, maybe its trying to split a ``string`` that is ``null``

Comment: Splitting a null still will give you a NullPointerException.

Comment: If you have a stack trace, post it here.

Comment: @Haphazard: he says there's no force close, so maybe he's catching the exception? @Nuktu: I would try printing to logcat the plain content of `stringFromFile`.

Comment: @bigstones: 
``05-30 17:44:16.511: DEBUG/READ(16817): stringFromFile`` `stringFromFile` has nothing in it

Comment: @Haphazard: @bigstones
``public void WriteItIn() throws IOException
 {
  Log.d("WRITE", "WriteItIn");
  FileOutputStream fOut = openFileOutput("stats.txt", Context.MODE_WORLD_READABLE);
  Log.d("WRITE", "create output stream: " + fOut);
  OutputStreamWriter osw = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
  Log.d("WRITE", "create output stream write: " + osw);
  ReadItIn();
  Log.d("WRITE", "called readitin.... " + counter + counterpos + counterneg);`` After the call of ``ReadItIn``, the values for ``counter``, ``counterpos``, and ``counterneg`` are all `0`
``DEBUG/WRITE(16817): called readitin.. 000``

Comment: So, they are all zeros but when you write to the file nothing happens?  It's always empty?  Or is there another problem?

Comment: @haphazard: Well if the counters from file are zero, it adds them to the current temp counters, and writes those values to file. To be honest, Im not sure if its the  write not writing properly, or the read not reading properly. I think its the reading

Comment: Check the file to see if it has anything written to it - that would definitely help us help you.

Comment: I checked and made sure that the file is being created, Im looking into checking what information is written to it now. 
One thing I did notice is that when I need to get data from the file, I never check to see if it exists, before the read takes place.

Comment: Well, for one thing, substitute `temper == ""` with `temper.equals("")` or similar.

Comment: @superjos Ye fixed that. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that as soon as you invoke `openFileOutput`, your *stats.txt* file gets erased every time again and again.

If you try to debug step by step your code, you can see that the first time you run the application, the file gets created with 0 size when you invoke `openFileOutput`. You can check this from the DDMS File explorer.

So when you read it it holds nothing, and nothing is read by `ReadItIn`. And when you write and close it, you can see from the DDMS File explorer that the file exists and has size > 0, rightly so.

But when you pass again by `WriteItIn`, as soon as you invoke `openFileOutput`, you can see from File explorer that the file size goes back to 0.

Comment: Thanks! So ill have to do some check, to see if the file exists? I dont know how I could do that with ``openFileOutput``, as its also needed to write to the file.

Comment: I don't know this API, but from the reference it looks like it will always recreate the file. If you don't want to recreate it, you can append-write to it, but I guess this is not what you're looking for. Have a look at the other Android file system APIs. What you can do, is split the two phases: 1) before you need the values, check if the file exists. 2) If it's there, open it for read, get the values and close it. 3) If not, assign the values their default initial value. 4) Then, when you think it's time to save back the values, recreate the file for write and save the values.